# Is there a way to create Mysql table where i can pass a PHP variable as the table name?

Tags: php, mysql

For example: $user= username. Create a table where table name is $user+image. The table name would be usernameimage.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Your question is essentially asking whether it is possible to create a table with a dynamic name in PHP.  Answer: Yes.

Comment: Creating multiple tables for users is __redundant__ Instead use one table `images` with foreign key `user_id`

Comment: **Yes**, you can. But it is not advisable to create tables for a single user. Review your schema for your system.

Comment: Plain straight, provide some code whats in your head for example? At first i was thinking you need ORM, at this point i dont know anymore :D

Comment: Yes I know it's not the norm. I noticed that most schema use a single table and then call the user ID. I'm working out a schema right now, but it's not a system where images,comment,etc are just pulled from the database. They have their own user levels and properties. So I'm considering the idea of going with many small tables over one large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First escape the input then use it in query.

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
mysqli_query("CREATE TABLE `".$name."` ( name VARCHAR(30), age INT, car VARCHAR(30))");
```

Escaping a string means to reduce ambiguity in quotes (and other characters) used in that string. For instance, when you're defining a string, you typically surround it in either double quotes or single quotes:

```
"Hello World."
```

But what if my string had double quotes within it?

```
"Hello "World.""
```

Now I have ambiguity - the interpreter doesn't know where my string ends. If I want to keep my double quotes, I have a couple options. I could use single quotes around my string:

```
'Hello "World."'
```

Or I can escape my quotes:

```
"Hello \"World.\""
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful.